# vlookup from name with multiple values excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list in excel that looks pretty much like that:

| Country | President | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | Obama | 2009 | 2017 |
| USA | Trump | 2017 | 2021 |
| France | Hollande | 2012 | 2017 |
| France | Macron | 2017 |  |
| Iran | Rouhani | 2013 |  |

I want to be able to extract the name of the president given a certain year - for example, be able to tell who was the French president in 2016.
Tried to use IF and VLOOKUP (incl. using TRUE), but didn't manage to work it out properly.

I don't mind creating another table, that would look like that:

| Year | USA | France | Iran |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016 | Obama | Hollande | Rouhani |
| 2017 | Trump | Macron | Rouhani |
| 2018 | Trump | Macron | Rouhani |

The missing cells are not my main issue, I could write them as 2050 for the matter... still haven't been able to make it work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try (in Microsoft365) the following:

[image]

Formula in `G2`:

```
=FILTER($B$2:$B$6,(($A$2:$A$6=G$1)*($C$2:$C$6<=$F2)*(IF($D$2:$D$6="",YEAR(TODAY()),$D$2:$D$6)>=$F2)))
```

Drag right and down.

Note that `TODAY()` is valatile.

Comment: I had something similar, but using LET and the assumption that all the presidents in a country are ordered by start date: =LET(pres,FILTER($B$2:$B$6,($C$2:$C$6<$F2)*($A$2:$A$6=G$1)),INDEX(pres,ROWS(pres),1))